# Remove a page form recommendation box

Tags: algorithm, facebook-social-plugins

I have recommendation box on [my site](http://www.strf.ru/).
There was [one popular page](http://www.strf.ru/material.aspx?CatalogId=221&d_no=44149), that doesn't exist any more.
But it still appears in recommendation box.

How can I remove this page from plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to `Page settings > Basic Information`, and unchecking `Show this map` where your location info is. 
It doesn't make any sense, but seems to solve the problem.